# system() call in C

Tags: visual-studio, system, wmplayer

I am writing my C code in Visual Studio and Im using the system() function in C to call wmplayer and play a sound:

`system("C:\\Windows_Media_Player\\wmplayer C:\\Users\\lfanning\\Downloads\\sound .wma");`

I call this in the middle of my main function however when I call it my program stops here and does not continue on with the next step.

How could I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Try writing it as follows

```
system("\"C:\Windows_Media_Player\wmplayer\" \"C:\Users\lfanning\Downloads\sound .wma\"");
```

Edit: Write it in a way that produces resulting string as "C:\Windows_Media_Player\wmplayer" "C:\Users\lfanning\Downloads\sound.wma" with quotes

Comment: No that doesnt solve it, the system() part works as in it opens wmplayer and the song plays its just the next line of code its a printf statement and that never prints to the screen

Comment: try closing wmplayer after it is opened and see if execution continues.